# Navigation Drawer Activity's menu items are not clickable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to create a new activity with drawer layout. To do this, I used Android Studio's default code generator: File -> New -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity. It created a bunch of files with fragments, drawer, and (jetpack) navigation support and their corresponding resources such as navigation file and layout files. I tried to run the new activity and it installed successfully. The problem is, my navigation drawer is not working. **The menu items in my drawer do not trigger any change in host navigation fragment**.

I've been stuck for a day already and have tried many solutions already and still, my menu items won't let me navigate to another destination.

Here is my resulting MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(
                item,
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)) ||
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The overridden onOptionsItemSelected() function is from Android's [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#8).

Here is my navigation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.bicolexpress.delivery.ui.main.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.bicolexpress.delivery.ui.main.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.bicolexpress.delivery.ui.main.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
</navigation>
```

Based on the codelab link above:

> If NavigationUI finds a menu item with the same ID as a destination on
> the current graph, it configures the menu item to navigate to that
> destination.

This is true for the generated menu items and destination IDs. But still, does not work. Can anyone point me to what I missed? I desperately need your help.

Android Studio Version: Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to copy the layout from [codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-navigation/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/navigation_activity.xml). And guess what, the click listeners worked!

I noticed that in codelab's layout, **the NavigationView was added into the DrawerLayout as the last child**. So I modified my activity_main.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
        
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```